# How to show keyboard on PopupWindow?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, popupwindow

I am using `PopupWindow` class and on `PopupWindow` I have one `EditText`, my problem is that when `PopupWindow` is visible and I click on `EditText` at that time the soft keyboard is not visible and I am not able to enter Input. Can anybody tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 15):

When you create a new `PopupWindow`, use another constructor method, you must set the `focusable = true;` only the view could be focusable, the soft keyboard will show .

```
public PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable) {}
```

The Default focusable is 'false'

Answer (score 5):

Took quite a bit to figure out, but here you go:

While creating the popup, I had to set the textbox (Edittext) to force opening the soft keyboard when receiving focus.

```
 txtBox.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus == true){
                InputMethodManager inputMgr = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMgr.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                inputMgr.showSoftInput(v, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            }
        }
    });
    txtBox.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this code 
**popupWindow.setFocusable(true);**

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View v, final boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus && editText.isEnabled() && editText.isFocusable()) {
                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        final InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.showSoftInput(editText,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked in my case. Tried using `popupWindow.update()`, but it didn't work for me.